# Query to remove duplicates in typescript in cloud function

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I have two queries-
For Friends

```
var friends = await admin
      .firestore()
      .collection('users')
      .where('friends', 'array-contains', userRef)
      .limit(2)
      .get();
```

For Other People

```
var otherPeople = await admin
      .firestore()
      .collection('users')
      .where('schoolRef', '==', schoolRefId)
      .limit(4 + 1)
      .get();
```

Now, I am merging both the queries into one object i.e. options

```
    var options = friends.docs.concat(otherPeople.docs);
```

For userId = "asdf0983qe12jkladf", I want to remove docs from options on the basis of below criteria.

1. remove doc where uid = userId
2. remove duplicate entries in options object also

Comment: [Filtering an array in JavaScript](https://www.google.com/search?q=Filtering+an+array+in+JavaScript) is quite common. Did you try anything yet to implement those two conditions?